# cViewSERVER: Missing cView.xml

Tags: xml, crystal-reports, scheduling

I'm trying to use the application cViewSERVER to schedule export/e-mailing Crystal Reports.

The problem however is, that when I open the "Manager", called cViewREMOTE, I need to open a file called cView.xml. The application won't work without this file.

I can't find this file anywhere on my computer!

Is there anyone who have experience using cViewSERVER?

I am using the trial version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did get cViewSERVER to run on a virtual machine (cView.xml is generated when the service is started from the control panel).

However! cViewSERVER was filled with bugs, and the "control panel", only worked half the time.

I ended up writing my own scheduler in the form of a C# Console Application, and running it as a service on a server.

In addition to this "scheduler", I also made an ASP.NET website for managing the service.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a scheduler in general, check Ken Hamady's website:
http://kenhamady.com/cru/comparisons/desktop-scheduling-engines
here is the feature matrix:
http://kenhamady.com/desktopschedulers.pdf

If you already decided that you are going to use cViewServer then your best shot is to contact their technical support.